# Why do I have to close the ZipOutputStream in a certain way in this situation?

Tags: java, file, outputstream, zipoutputstream

I have two examples :

Example 1:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream baous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();     
    FileOutputStream fouscrx = new FileOutputStream(new File(output, "example"))) {
        try (ZipOutputStream zous = new ZipOutputStream(baous)) {
            for (File file: files) {
                try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.getPath().substring(output.getPath().length() + 1));
                    zous.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                        zous.write(bytes, 0, length);
                    }
                    zous.closeEntry();
                }
            }
        }
        baous.writeTo(fouscrx);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

Example 2:

```
try (ByteArrayOutputStream baous = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
          ZipOutputStream zous = new ZipOutputStream(baous);
       FileOutputStream fouscrx = new FileOutputStream(new File(output, "example"))) {
            for (File file: files) {
                try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(file.getPath().substring(output.getPath().length() + 1));
                    zous.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
                    int length;
                    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
                        zous.write(bytes, 0, length);
                    }
                    zous.closeEntry();
                }
            }
            baous.writeTo(fouscrx);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {} catch (IOException ex) {}
```

The **second** example doesn't work as I would like it to do.
What I mean is that the file content is not empty but it'
s as if the zip file was corrupted.

**I would like you to tell me how come the first example does not work.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ZipOutputStream` [has to do several operations at the end of the stream](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.java#ZipOutputStream.finish%28%29) to finish the zip file, so it's necessary for it to be closed properly.  (Generally speaking, pretty much every stream *should* be closed properly, just as good practice.)

Comment: Sort of undefined behaviour. My guess is that the FileOutputStream is closed first, which implies a flush, but there was data that needed to be consumed by the nested stream first.

Comment: @chikamatsu I think you have the wrong file on the right side of that picture - it seems to be a text file by the values inside it, so it's not a zipped file, and you are not comparing the right files.

Comment: Oops, you're right, i made a mistake, here's the right screenshot:
(again, the wrong one is on the left)
http://puu.sh/g5pj3.png

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like the try-with-resources autoclosing order is important, and the ZipOutputStream has to be closed first when unwinding things. Autoclosing happens in reverse order of their creation in this context.

What happens if you reorder your second example so the ZipOutputStream is after the FileOutputStream? (Though placing the ZipOutputStream in its own try-catch block is clearer code if you ask me. We separate out the related and unrelated streams and handle the auto-closing in an easily readable manner.)

UPDATE

FWIW, this is the sort of idiom I have used in the past when streaming a zip into a buffered output stream:

```
try (final ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(zipFile.toString())))) { ... }
```

Comment: It happens the exact same thing (it did not work, but maybe the file content is not the same). What i don't understand is the behavior of both ByteArrayOutputStream and ZipOutputStream.

Comment: Not sure, then. I just realized that the FileOutputStream isn't really used until you decide to write out the ByteArrayOutputStream. So it really ought to be in its own try block after you have finalized the zip, including closing it.